# how can i retrieve my private mode data after factory reset

Tags: backup

I got my samsung s6 edge phone and there was some data which was moved to private mode but due to some unavoidable reasons I got to factory reset my phone. but as it was connected to my gmail and was being backed up so i got all my pictures back in gallery but none of my picture is there which i had moved to private mode... I got s6 edge... any help there how to get those data back which was in private mode?

Comment: Two words: black magic. No it is not possible since images weren't backed up, it could be maybe done by some professionals but if you used phone there is great chance that is data overwritten and it would be too expensive if its not so important data.

Answer (score 0):

If you did a factory reset there is no way you can retrieve your data, but if you had a backup of your rom there should be no problem recovering it